# concise alternative to a while loop

Tags: javascript

The following code works fine to generate an array of 6 random values (or however many are specified by `iterations`).  I'm wondering if there's a more concise way than using a `while` loop to achieve the same result.

```
const seedValue = 31;
const iterations = 6;

let i = 0;
const results = [];

while (i < iterations) {
  results.push(seedValue * Math.random());
  i++;
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not the most concise nor efficient, but it is an alternative in a sense that the approach is totally different and shorter than what you provided:

```js
const seedValue = 31;
const iterations = 6;
const results = Array(iterations).fill(seedValue).map(v => v * Math.random())

console.log(results)
```

The idea comes from other language's `range()` function, which creates a sequence of values that you can iterate over. JS has no such function, but you can emulate with an array. In this case, I created an empty array of 6 slots, filled them up with the seed value, and transform each by multiplying each by `Math.random()`.

If you insist using a loop, consider a `for` loop instead. This puts the counter's initialization and increment in the same line as the opening, removing the need for separate lines:

```
const results = [];

for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  results.push(seedValue * Math.random());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to use [`Array.from`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.from). While `Array.from` is mostly used to create an [`Array`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-objects) from an [*Iterable*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-iterable-interface) or an [*Iterator*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-iterator-interface), it can also be used to create an `Array` from any [*array-like object*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-lengthofarraylike), where an *array-like object* is simply any object with a `length` property.

The second argument to `Array.from` is a mapping function which produces the elements of the `Array`.

So, the whole thing would look something like this:

```js
const seedValue = 31;
const iterations = 6;

const results = Array.from(
  { length: iterations },
  _ => seedValue * Math.random()
);

console.log(results);
```